# Can we use quotation marks to refer to a specific term on a website?

Tags: punctuation, style-manuals

Here's the paragraph:

> My first inclination is to find the search bar and type the word “Graphic design”. But, there is no search bar. On the top left panel, there are 3 tabs : “Courses”, “Programs”, and “Discover new”. The highlight on the tab, "Courses", indicates that i am on this tab. The other two tabs are : "Programs" and "Discover new". With "Programs" i am not clear what it is specifically. What is the difference between "Courses" and "Programs".

I read that quotation marks should only be used around words as scare quotes. Here, i am referring to a specific term on a website. So, is it appropriate to use quotation marks around them, or not?

Also, i put quotation marks around the word Graphic design. Is that inappropriate?

Comment: Typically, all of the words you enclosed in quotation marks would be put in a bold font instead. Or sometimes in all caps. It would be unusual to use quotation marks rather than some other stylistic device. The quotes around "Graphic design" is somewhat more normal, but more common would be italics, a courier font face, or single quotation marks.

Comment: What are "scare quotes"?

Comment: Hello. As per google dictionary : "quotation marks placed round a word or phrase to draw attention to an unusual or arguably inaccurate use."

Comment: Thank you so much, @JasonBassford. Your comment clarified my doubts. However, wouldn't putting all these terms in Bold face in a long paragraph look very unappealing?